# PHP - Not able display images which src comes from database

Tags: php, image

```
<i><img src="<?php echo $path ;?>" alt="<?php echo $path;?>" style="width:250px;height:250px;"></i>
```

Here `$path` is an absolute path to that image on a separate drive(E:/)

Comment: absolute image path not work in src. use site url in image src

Comment: can You explain briefly please?

Comment: just copy the image to your script directory and link like: `src="image_name.ext"`.

Comment: @ManishJesani even this gif is not displaying instead its displaying the alt text

Comment: Please see this link https://jsfiddle.net/manishjesani/yjw9Lkc1/2/

Comment: Thanks this link works in my script but my uploaded pics are in my local drive E,and my project folder is in C/inetpub/wwwroot and the php is not able to load the local image file. Tried file:///$path too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are running your script from the server, cause a PHP script.
Lets say you have your script in the directory named `myFirstScript`, inside this folder you have a file named `script.php` where you wrote your this code.

```
<i><img src="<?php echo $path ;?>" alt="<?php echo $path;?>" style="width:250px;height:250px;"></i>
```

So the question is what is the `$path` here? OK, don't worry, because you are using this `$path` to the src of an image so it is a image file. And this image file must in the same directory named `myFirstScript`. Say you have the image named `image.jpg`. so your path is: `$path = 'image.jpg';`

Example:

```
<?php $path = 'image.jpg';?>
<i><img src="<?php echo $path ;?>" alt="<?php echo $path;?>" style="width:250px;height:250px;"></i>
```

Real time Example:

```
<?php $path = 'http://placehold.it/350x150';?>
<i><img src="<?php echo $path ;?>" alt="<?php echo $path;?>" style="width:250px;height:250px;"></i>
```